# Finding minimum values of a function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I am trying to find the minimum values for the following
function:
$f(x)=(x-3)^4 + (x-5)^4 + (x-9)^4 + (x+10)^4$

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use numerical approximation (unless you want to use the cubic formula). The derivative has one non-rational real root and two non-real roots.

Comment: yep, this is just brute force exercise. not all equations have nice solutions.

Comment: Maybe try the AM-GM inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=(x-3)^4 + (x-5)^4 + (x-9)^4 + (x+10)^4$$
$$f'(x)=16 x^3-84 x^2+2580 x+476=0$$

If you follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) for one real solution, $f'(x)=0$ when
$$x_*=\frac{7}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{811}}{2}  \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{9639}{811 \sqrt{811}}\right)\right)\approx  -0.183363$$ Since this number is much smaller than $3$, $5$, $9$ and $10$ you have a good approximation computing $f(0)=17267$ instead of $f(x_*)=17223.3$.